Netlify suspended all my Solana dApps
Netlify has blocked my account access and suspended my two Solana dApps with no warning. These dApps are still being tested in devnet. Has anyone dealt with this problem before?




Netlify is known to be somewhat unfriendly to crypto, and will sometimes shut sites (even non-crypto) down without warning. I'd recommend using a provider like Vercel or Cloudflare Pages instead.
